# Dell XPS 15 9520 wifi issues

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, iwlwifi, xps

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on Dell XPS 15 9520 (2022 model), but I immediately noticed some wifi issues that occurred randomly when loading web pages that took longer than normal and more noticeably when doing meeting using google meet or zoom (for example the video and audio of the other participants sometimes goes out of sync).

As suggested in other posts I disabled wifi power save by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` but didn't work

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Next, I installed Ubuntu 22.10 which has a newer kernel (5.19) hoping this issues would be fixed. This helped and the wifi seem more stable, but from time to time it happens again.

Some information about my system:

**1** System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**2** Hardware:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 01
       serial: 14:75:5b:60:b0:c6
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-26-generic firmware=71.058653f6.0 so-a0-gf-a0-71.uc ip=192.168.1.33 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:610-60f irq:16 memory:6187194000-6187197fff
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem, but the detected product is "Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi", but according to the [xps specs](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/xps-15-9520-laptop/xps-15-9520-setup-and-specifications/wireless-module?guid=guid-9268df17-896f-4186-ad5c-ce736e3aab6d&lang=en-us) the wifi card is "Intel Killer 1675 (AX211)"

**3** Logs:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   13.732065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   13.748716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[   13.750755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   13.750775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[   13.751322] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 so-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.894329] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[   14.071788] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded PNVM version 881c99e1
[   14.086625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
[   14.156415] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 14:75:5b:60:b0:c6
[   14.175637] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[ 1224.317127] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e2:b9:e5:9f:44:99 on queue 3, stopping BA session on TID 0
[ 1467.273317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e2:b9:e5:9f:44:99 on queue 4, stopping BA session on TID 0
[ 4073.574108] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e0:b9:e5:9f:44:91 on queue 2, stopping BA session on TID 0
[ 4075.904612] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[ 4075.905434] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[ 4075.906719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[ 5925.410865] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e2:b9:e5:9f:44:99 on queue 2, stopping BA session on TID 0
[10433.137393] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[10433.138484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[10531.539579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e2:b9:e5:9f:44:99 on queue 11, stopping BA session on TID 0
[20476.109639] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[20476.111848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x71b
[20482.540543] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: reached 20 old SN frames from e2:b9:e5:9f:44:99 on queue 11, stopping BA session on TID 0
```

#### Notes

- I noticed that sometimes the logs `Unhandled alg: 0x71b` match the time when the wifi issues occur, but couldn't find any solution for it.
- When these issues occur, the speed test measure less than 1Mbps (my usual speed is ~60Mbps)
- A workaround that seems to work is going offline mode, and then connecting to wifi again

---

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Ubuntu 23.04, and now to 23.10 with kernel >=6.2 solved all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered random slowness with my dell xps 15 9520.

Solved it by using kernel 6.1.1 using mainline.
Please note that I'm using Ubuntu 22.10.
But I reckon Ubuntu 22.04 also allow kernel 6.1.1.
Those aren't LTS kernel, but you can switch back to LTS kernel if you want to.